# Database class for Php (MySQL + MemCached)

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I'm looking for a solid MySQL class for Php that has support for memcached built-in. I've searched Google, Phpclasses.org etc. and come up empty handed which leads me to believe I may be asking the wrong question.

Any advice and/or help on the matter - or a point in the direction of such a class - would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would say get the best DB class and the best MemCached class and then you can write a wrapper to integrate the two. chances are that something that is all in one will not be very good, hard to maintain and a general mess.

something like http://www.doctrine-project.org/ for the db, MemCache is pretty simple. The other approach would be a framework like cakephp or zend etc